# Selecting columns/rows of a matrix in Julia

Tags: select, matrix, julia

this is a very basic problem but I didn't find any hints on it. Let's say I have a 2x4 matrix and I want to reduce the dimension of the matrix to only these columns that are in the sum larger than 1:

```
A=rand(2,4)
ind = sum(A,1).>1
```

That gives me an indicator of the columns I want to retain. Naively one would assume that I can do that:

```
A[:,ind]
```

which doesn't work as ind is a BitArray and only for Bool Arrays this is allowed, i.e., the following works

```
A[:,[true,true,false,true]]
```

in return, the following does work:

```
A[A.>0.5]
```

But it returns a vector of filtered elements.
What is the logic behind this and how do I solve my problem?

Comment: I found out that I get the correct matrix with
`A[:,find(ind)]`
but it's unclear to me why it has to be done that way.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Julia 0.3? This works in Julia 0.4.5 (latest stable).

Comment: True. Okay so this has been ''fixed".. thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is fixed by using a version of Julia which is >=v0.4.